# Is there a way to abort post flagging?

Tags: feature-request, flags

Sometimes when I flag posts I make mistakes like I find better category from different flags, or user posts a comment that changes the meaning of the question etc. Is there some functionality that allows to withdraw active flag? If not I think it would be quite useful feature.

Comment: see also: [Unable to retract VLQ flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333961/839601)

Comment: @gnat sorry I couldn't see it while I wrote the question.